# How can I keep terminal running after closing app?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I created a desktop shortcut to run a script. However, I am not sure how I can keep terminal open once I close the app or if it crashes. I am fairly new to coding so please forgive me if this has been asked before. I tried other forums posts but I couldn't seem to get it to work for this one.

```
Name=Test
Comment=
Exec=bash -c "$HOME/test_folder/scripts/test.sh"
Icon=/usr/share/icons/test.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal window cannot remain open without a program running in it.
So in order to keep the terminal open you have to make sure the command running in it does not exit.
There are various ways to achieve this.
One aspect that needs consideration is when and how the terminal shall be closed eventually.

In your case, since your command is `bash` running a script which you control, perhaps the simplest solution is to add the line:

```
read -p "Press ENTER to continue"
```

to the end of that script.
This will cause the script to wait for a line of input before exiting, so the terminal will only close when you hit the ENTER key while it has the focus.

If your `Exec=` line contains a command you cannot or do not want to modify then an alternative solution would be to append the `read` command to it, for example:

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c '/usr/local/bin/coolprog ; read -p "Press any key to continue"'
```

The terminal will start a shell to run this command line, and the `read` command will cause that shell to wait for a line of input before exiting.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I will now try experiment for terminal to ask to 'relaunch' instead of exiting out of terminal

Comment: Good answer, but I don't think anyone tested the `Exec=` part.

Comment: Good answer, but I don't think anyone tested the Exec= part. Anyway, I was under the impression that you rather wanted a terminal prompt after the app closes.

Comment: You're right. An ill-conceived last moment edit. Sorry about that. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

- On your `Exec=` line, remove the `bash -c "` and `¨` at the end: there is no need. Just directly specify the full pathname of your script if it is not in a directory in your PATH.
- Edit your script, and add a line `bash`. that way, the terminal will stay open on a prompt after the previous command in the script has finished.